# How to enable javascript webview for API 15

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to make webview which load javascript, but not working in API 15. I already test on API 21 and working. Anyone know to make it working? Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    view.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack(); 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` must return `true`, only if you want to load url different from original, or not to load at all. In this case can return false and load url in usual way. If your page executes JS by loading 'javascript:' link,  you can return `false` for all urls, started with `javascript:`. Note, that on SDK 24+, shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) called instead.